# What catches this return statement from within the reducer in redux?

Tags: redux, react-redux

In this example I am listening to a `DO_SEARCH` action type and returning the payload of the action. But I want to do some stuffs after I catch the `DO_SEARCH` action type and I can not do it inside the reducer, as it must be a pure function.

```
export default function (state=null, action) {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'DO_SEARCH':
           return action.payload;
           break;
    }
    return state; 
};
```

My question is what actually catches this return ?

Say I have a text box and a button. And I am invoking a `DO_SEARCH` action type after I click the button. The payload is actually the text in the textbox. So where do I catch this payload that I just returned from the reducer ?

I want to do some stuffs on the text in the textbox. Where do I actually put this piece of code ? Definitely not inside `reducers` as they are pure functions. Is it inside the components that I actually implement my logic ?

Comment: Why is this not  a pure function?

Comment: @Scimonster I just edited my question. : )

Comment: What sort of stuff do you want to do?

Comment: @Scimonster comparing the text to a whole lot of another text. Search sort of stuff

Comment: So why can't that be done in a reducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle your state within the container. What your reducer does is that it returns you the state, You can catch this inside your container using the `mapStateToProps` function and make use of `connect` to make that state available as a prop to your component like

```
import 'reducerText' from '/path/to/reducer';
import {connect} form 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
      }
      render() {
         console.log(this.props.text);
         return (<div>Hello {this.props.text}</div>);
      }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
   return {
      text: state.reducerText
   }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: So I put my logic inside the container ? say `onClick` function

Comment: Yes, you can do that and this time you make use of reducer state as a prop